# Do I need to stop GPS usage once MapView activity is closed?

Tags: android, location, android-mapview

Currently I display user's location at MapView:

```
MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);     
mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);      
myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
```

But once user closes `MapView` activity (press back button) or even closes `MainActivity` (presses back again), GPS icon is still displayed in the status bar. Looks like GPS is still used. Should I do something in my code to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to stop GPS usage to avoid battery draining, following methods will stop GPS usage used in relevant methods like OnPause, onStop, onDestroy:

```
MyLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
LocationManager.removeUpdates(LocationListener);
```

Comment: I don't have LocationListener, so only first line is applicable, right? This line works fine.